# Facebook canvas game integrate with node js and socket io from localhost

Tags: node.js, facebook, socket.io, integrate

I have tried to search google on the topic. However, I cannot found the solution yet. So now, I would like to rest my problem here if someone has experienced it.

I have a game using nodejs and socket io which I have already setup the ssl ("https"). Moreover, I have tested game from localhost without nodejs and socket, it is working fine.

My issue is, when I use nodejs and socket io integrate to facebook, it always appear the message "Cannot POST /"

I checked the developer tool on chrome

Go to security tab and found this message:

("Active content with certificate errors
You have recently allowed content loaded with certificate errors (such as scripts or iframes) to run on this site.")

Really appreciate if someone can help me!!! Thanks

Comment: Is your SSL fully "ok", no intermediate certificates missing? (Google "ssl check", and test using the first few results.) Are you embedding everything else (scripts, stylesheets, images) via HTTPS as well? Is you app handling the initial POST request correctly? (Only have a route set for GET is a common problem.)

Comment: my ssl is fine, but don't know why facebook is not detected into iframe

Comment: And I don’t know what "why facebook is not detected into iframe" is even supposed to mean …?

Comment: I meant the files load into iframe, seem like it doesn't recognize the url.

Comment: Then most likely your app is not handling POST requests against the given URL correctly.

Comment: you can check out this link 
https://apps.facebook.com/gamesocketdemo/?fb_appcenter=1

Comment: Now, I have used Heroku instead of localhost development. However, I still wonder and want to figure out the problem with Localhost development. Anyways, thanks for your participated dude.